# JSONParseException while importing data to mongodb

Tags: java, json, mongodb, parsing, exception

I'm trying to import a json file to Mongodb using Java drivers, but I got this  exception

> Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
>       at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.read(JSON.java:301)
>       at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseString(JSON.java:455)
>       at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:204)
>       at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:263)
>       at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:227)
>       at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:155)
>       at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:92)
>       at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:73)

Out of some 200000 documents, only around 4000 are being imported to database. Can anyone please tell me how I should fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Following is the code I wrote:

```
class ClickApp {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ClickApp cl = new ClickApp();

    Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongo.getDB("db");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("col");

    cl.JsonfiletoMongodb("/home/jsonfile/ClickApp.json", db, collection);

}

public void JsonfiletoMongodb(String pathToFile, DB db, DBCollection coll) {
    // open file
    FileInputStream fstream = null;
    try {
        fstream = new FileInputStream(pathToFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("File not found");
        return;
    }
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));


    String str;

   try {
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null)  {

            DBObject dbObject;
            dbObject = (DBObject) JSON.parse(strLine);
            try {    
                coll.insert(dbObject);
            }
                catch(MongoException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        br.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another quick thing you can do is paste the json content into http://jsonlint.com/ and you can identify if there are any issues in the json content.

Then if no issue with json content use mongoimport.exe to quickly import the data.

Comment: The json file is very large, I can not paste the whole content to jsonlint. Thanks for the suggestion. There might be issues with the json format.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this command. [Syntax reference from MongoDb site](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)

```
.\mongoimport.exe --db test --collection restaurants --drop --file ..\data\primer-dataset.json
```